# What is the minimum spacing I need for Daltile Restore Subway Tile?

Tags: tiling

The literature for the tile say that it can be lugged and that it is self spacing. Surely it needs some spacing though right? I thought the grout needs to connect through to the cement board. If I do what the manufacturer says, the grout will just sit on top of the tile. Is that acceptable?

I've read lots of conflicting information. I think I want to just use 1/16" spacers just to be safe, but I would appreciate clarification as well.

[image]

Comment: "can be" lugged and self spacing (*if* you order that version) or "is" lugged and self spacing? That would matter. Can you show a picture of the edge of the tile?

Comment: The sides of tile are unglazed; it'll key into that just fine. Providing you do your job with the float which is push harder than you want to. If you're not dripping with sweat by the time you're done then you didn't do it right.

Comment: Using non-sanded grout will be what is needed here. Sanded grout is typically used in larger joints

Answer (score 2):

A "lugged, self-spacing" tile has spacers (lugs, or nubs) formed into it. They stick out from the edge of the tile. Typically they give a 1/16" grout line, though that will vary with maker and tile. Most of the grout line is fully open. Where the lugs are, they touch below the glaze surface.

You don't need additional space, there will be space to grout into, but if you want a larger grout line you can (just beware of consistently placing your spacers off the lugs or on the lugs, not a mixture.)

Comment: The plain square tiles I used 30 years ago had lugs. The snazzy new ones we just picked up a couple of weeks ago don't. I bought spacers to go with the new tiles. +1